# Generating set and cardinality

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with a generating set $\{g_1,\dotsc,g_n\}$. Is there any relation between $|G|$ and $n$? Is there an upper bound for $|G|$ in $n$?

Comment: No, there's no upper bound: the symmetric group is generated by 2 elements.

Comment: The group $\mathbb Z_n$ is generated by 1 element.

Comment: @YCor Can we define a metric on a finitely generated group with some "nice"  properties? Do anyone try to make a finitely generated group, a metric space?

Comment: Yes :) it's very common, have you googled anything? look up "Cayley graph". (You could have found! googling ["finitely generated group" "metric space"] yields https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_metric among the first answers.)

Comment: @YCor How much the range of the word metric is important? What information can be obtained from the rang of the word metric? Is it possible to decide that a f.g. gorup is finitely presented by the rang. Is it clear that the finiteness of  a group $G$ is equivalent to the finiteness of the rang?

Comment: For groups with finite generating subsets, yes obviously.